# Python Threading - Will this keep spawning new threads?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
while True:
    try:
        for i in range(2):
            t1 = Thread(target = grab_data_from_queue)
            t1.daemon = True
            t1.start() # start the thread
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
      print '\n[!] Received keyboard interrupt, quitting threads.\n'
      exit()
```

The function that's running is waiting for items to be added to the queue - I want this to be a long-running task, so the function sits and processes tasks.

However, will this keep spawning new threads continuously, I don't want to leave it running overnight and there be thousands of handing threads.

Update:
A potential fix would be to do the following as per comments:

```
while True:
    if q.empty():
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        try:
            for i in range(2):
                t1 = Thread(target = grab_data_from_queue)
                t1.daemon = True
                t1.start() # start the thread
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
          print '\n[!] Received keyboard interrupt, quitting threads.\n'
          exit()
```

Comment: Have you tried only entering that for loop if there is data in the queue? I.e. test for data, if data, then thread and give it the data. Otherwise, sleep, etc.

Comment: Updated question - something like that?

Comment: This will keep spawning new threads if the previous threads are not exited. Is the goal to have 2 long running consumers or to reap the threads as soon as they complete `grab_data_from_queue` and replace them with new threads?

Comment: Either complete the threads and spawn new ones or just keep using those - either way

Answer (score 0):

if `grab_data_from_queue func` is a cpu-intensive job, you can try to use `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()`, then your code maybe like this:

```
pool = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
while True:
    if q.empty():
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        futures = set()
        with pool as executor:
            future = executor.submit(grab_data_from_queue, data)
            futures.add(future)
        try:
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
                exc = future.exception()
                if exc:
                    raise exc

        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
          print '\n[!] Received keyboard interrupt, quitting threads.\n'
          exit()
```